# Change setuptools gcc buildpath for Python

Tags: python, gcc, setuptools

I'm trying to install MySQLdb-python on a server I don't have root on. It doesn't have appropriate mysql development files that `python setup.py build` would usually compile into _mysql.so. I've obtained the files, and placed them in my home directory, however I can't get the build script to find them.

When I run the build command, the script spits out a massive gcc line:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.4 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.4/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
```

the -I/usr/include/mysql is the problem. I need to change that to -I/home/user/mysql. I've tried to manually run the gcc line myself, but I know absolutely nothing about gcc or c in general.

Is there any python-y way to change the include directories?

Answer (score 0):

I believe inside file setup.py, there is a list call `include_dirs`. You can include your folder here. If there is the `setup.cfg` file with the setup archive, you can put your path inside that too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the file: site.cfg
in the 'options' section there is a config key named 'mysql_config' which is a mysql command line tool. just set it to your own mysql install path